# How do I convert an Illustrator file that is 8x10 to a high quality 300 dpi jpeg?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I tried rastorizing it (this happens to be an all text 8x10 print) and it turned from purple to blue. I tried going to Export>saved as a jpeg>changed color to RGB, made quality 10 (maximum), did "progressive" compression method with 3 scans, resolution changed to 300 ppi, anti-aliasing I left on type optimized (hinted) and hit "ok" - and it looks perfect except my 8x10 print turned into a square jpeg! New to this so any dumbed down advice would be amazing!

Comment: Do you have invisible objects outside the artboard? When you do an export, it will export everything even objects outside of the artboard.

Comment: Despite what most people will tell you, I normally just open the *.ai file in Photoshop. It will allow you to chose where the image is cropped to on import (i.e. Trim line/bleed etc) and the size/resolution. Then save as JPG as you normally would in PS.

Answer (score 1):

The first dialogue box that pops up when you click on export has a "Use Artboards" checkbox at the bottom. Try that, but make sure your artboard matches the area you want to save. Command+O will let you resize it if needed.